# Invalid checksum when generating BIP-39 Mnemonic

Tags: mnemonic-seed, javascript

I am trying to generate a mnemonic seed in Javascript, and while everything seems to be working, I am not getting a mnemonic with a correct checksum. Here is my implementation:

```js
export const generateMnemonic = async () => {
    const ent = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    const entBits = toBinString(ent);
    const entHash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(
        await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", ent)
    ));
    const entHashBits = toBinString(entHash)
    const checksum = entHashBits.slice(0, 4);
    const entCS = entBits + checksum;
    const chunks = Array.from(hendecadsFromBits(entCS));
    const words = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        words.push(wordlist[chunks[i]]);
    }
    return words;
};

const toBinString = (bytes) => bytes.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), '')

function* hendecadsFromBits(bits) {
    let i = 0;
    let val = 0;
    for (const bit of bits) {
        if (i == 11) {
            yield val;
            i = val = 0;
        }
        val |= bit << i++;
    }
    if (i > 0) yield val;
}
```

Is it because I am padding the bytes with zeros?

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a few problem in your code, in the `hendecadsFromBits` function, you need to use the numeric value of bit and in the `generateMnemonic` function, when you call `hendecadsFromBits`, you need to pass the result to `Array.from()`

Here is how you could fix your code:

```js
export const generateMnemonic = async () => {
    const ent = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    const entBits = toBinString(ent);
    const entHash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(
        await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", ent)
    ));
    const entHashBits = toBinString(entHash)
    const checksum = entHashBits.slice(0, 4);
    const entCS = entBits + checksum;
    const chunks = Array.from(hendecadsFromBits(entCS));
    const words = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        words.push(wordlist[chunks[i]]);
    }
    return words.join(' ');
};

const toBinString = (bytes) => bytes.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(2).padStart(8, '0'), '')

function* hendecadsFromBits(bits) {
    let i = 0;
    let val = 0;
    for (const bit of bits) {
        if (i == 11) {
            yield val;
            i = val = 0;
        }
        val |= parseInt(bit, 10) << i++;
    }
    if (i > 0) yield val;
}
```